# Accessing a Function from HTML inside of a JS Module

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

So I can currently enqueing the script as so.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'myScripts', WPEX_JS_DIR_URI .'/myScripts.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.7.5', true );
```

And I am currently attempting to use the function as seen below.

```
(function($) {


     function vote_up () {
        $(".voteButton").html("Hello jQuery");
     }


})(jQuery);
```

And I am just for the sake of getting it work attempting to call it with an onclick method,

```
<div class="button voteButton" onclick="vote_up()">Vote Up !</div>
```

I understand that I may need to assign the function like this,

```
var foo = (function ($) {
```

Although when I do this and attempt to call it with

```
foo.vote_up()
```

I still cannot get it to work.

Am I missing something simple?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to invoke the method as object method (`foo.vote_up()`) then return an object from you immediate function instead of only create a function, and then invoke the method. I think that you're looking for something like:

```
var foo = (function($) {
     return {
      vote_up : function () {
        $(".voteButton").html("Hello jQuery");
      }
     }
})(jQuery);

foo.vote_up();
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: Ah brilliant right off the bat thank you! I can accept in 8 Minutes

Comment: Just a quick question to clarify is it okay to run ajax requests within the vote_up function?

Comment: @jackdh yes I think it's perfectly ok, only take care the use of `this` refer the context you expect (of course in case you need it).

Comment: Yep sorry got distracted!